# Libgdx I don't understand why libgdx put this line of code in ActionSequence test:stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));

Tags: java, libgdx

Libgdx I don't understand why libgdx put this line of code in ActionSequence test:

```
stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they want to make sure that the test runs at least with 30 FPS. Assume getDeltaTime() returns 5 seconds for what ever reason. Then the 1/30 seconds will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the minimum value of the delta time and `1/30f` makes sure that the value is never bigger than `1/30f` (which is about two times the "normal" value of delta time).

Limiting the delta time makes sure that you can't have a too high delta value. This usually happens when something, like the garbage collector for example, causes a hickup. During such hickup the previous screen is still visible to the user. You don't want to deviate too much from that, even if there was a hickup, to provide the best user experience.

For example: consider a tetris like game where the blocks in a grid fall down at a given speed. If the block is located at the top it will slowly fall down and the user can move it to the left and right. Now consider that a hickup occurs for some reason and the delta time is not capped. Then the block would hang at the top during the hickup and then the next frame it would be all the way down, while the user didnt had the chance to move it in between.